# Export OSM data from my own server

Tags: openstreetmap

I have a OSM server running (Geoserver + PostGIS + OSM Planet Data) on my own server.

Now, I need to offer to my users the same functionality of openstreetmap.org to extract data from the database using a web interface.

How can I do this?

Comment: Ok. Found `--read-apidb` to `Export a planet file from a local PostgreSQL database.` Like `osmosis --read-apidb host="x" database="x" user="x" password="x" --write-xml file="planet.osm"`. But how to filter data? Same parameter list used to import?